# Drupal 7 Video.js views count

Tags: drupal, video, drupal-7, html5-video, video.js

I need a suggestion, I'm using the `video.js`HTML5 player on Drupal with the module that acts as a bridge and the `Video module` for manage the video system.

At this point I would need to count the number of views of a video.

So my question is this:

Exist something ready to use in one of these drupal modules(or in another) or in the video.js library?(for example, some plugin)

I need count the actual number of times that a video is started... I have found several solutions that count the number of times the page is opened .. but I do not need this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin may work for you - it pushes video events to Google Analytics.

https://github.com/mickey/videojs-ga